# Running Nmap on Ubuntu

Tags: server, python, 17.04, nmap

I am running a python script that executes nmap on a given set of parameters. The point is to automate this so i do not have to interact with the cli at all. Every time I run my script, I am prompted with the error message:

```
 'You requested a scan type which requires root priveleges.\nQUITTING!\n'
```

I understand that I can put "sudo" in front of my command, but the goal of my script is to not interact with the cli at all. I gave ownership of the script to my user, but still have the same error. Is there a way in which i can run nmap as a super user everytime without having to give the sudo command? All help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Nmap requires root permissions for many things (see below). Because of this, it is tempting to use various schemes (sudo NOPASSWD, setuid, etc.) to allow users to run it without providing a root password. But this is **extremely dangerous**, since it is trivial to use Nmap to launch any other command or shell. For example: `nmap --script <(echo 'os.execute("/bin/sh")')`

Fortunately, Nmap has [experimental support for Linux capabilities](https://secwiki.org/w/Running_nmap_as_an_unprivileged_user). By installing Nmap with the `CAP_NET_RAW`, `CAP_NET_ADMIN`, and `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capabilities, you can more safely allow unprivileged users to run it. Nmap itself cannot detect that it has these capabilities, so you must use the `--privileged` option to inform it to try using them regardless of UID. More discussion is available in the link above.

---

Nmap requires root permissions for everything except:

- TCP Connect scan (`-sT`)
- Reverse-DNS name resolution
- Host discovery ("ping") methods except for TCP Connect (`-PS`)
- Service and Application Version Detection (`-sV`)
- Most Nmap Scripting Engine (NSE) scripts

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add that specific command to `sudoers` file,

```
Cmnd_Alias    NMAP = /path/to/nmap, /path/to/script

username      ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: NMAP
```

Something along this line would allow you to script your `sudo` commands, but not need to type a password for that command specifically. You could choose to just do it for that script / user combo so that everything in the script is run as root, or you could do it for the `nmap` command specifically, and have many `sudo` entries in your script.

Pick your poison...

Comment: Please be aware that Nmap is trivial to convert to a shell, so giving `sudo` access to Nmap is the same as giving that user full root access. This is the same reason Nmap should not be installed 'suid root'.

Comment: Which is why you would be choosing who would be allowed access (remember, the OP has full sudo access already, meaning root shell availability, so that is not so much a concern). If the question was how to allow a non priv user who needs to stay non priv and has NO access to sudo the ability to run nmap in a privileged way, then that would need to be kept in consideration.